# Cordova Xcode Build errors with cordova 2.3.0

Tags: cordova, xcode4.5, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

When upgrading Xcode project from Cordova 2.2.0 to 2.3.0 Build failed : 3 errors ''MainCommandDelegate' cannot use 'super' because it is a root class'

- (id)getCommandInstance:(NSString*)className { return [super getCommandInstance:className]; }
- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command { return [super execute:command]; }
- (NSString*)pathForResource:(NSString*)resourcepath; { return [super pathForResource:resourcepath]; }

and 1 error : ''MainCommandQueue' cannot use 'super' because it is a root class'
- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command { return [super execute:command]; }

Please Help!
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved :

We moved the new MainViewController.m into our Project. In addition we have to declare these interfaces and import the related header files:

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandQueue.h>

@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController
@end

@interface MainCommandDelegate : CDVCommandDelegateImpl
@end

@interface MainCommandQueue : CDVCommandQueue
@end
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. What file did u updated with above imports and declaring interfaces?   I tried updating them into  MainviewController.h but I got compile errors about "/Users/wug/Projs/Learning/hello_cordova2/ios/hello_cordova2/Classes/MainViewController.h:30: Cordova/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you @GeorgeW - did you manage to solve it?

Comment: in project | target | Build phase | link or linker library;  make sure you add libCordova.a or something like that. Good luck.

Comment: Wonderful was stuck for an hour on this, your solution fixed Mine thanks!! Dream1, i solved it on 2.6.0